LyX shows warning that the macros file I'm using is encoded in "auto-legacy" while parent is "utf-8", how to solve this?
here's the error message:

but when I check the macros file it's encoded in utf-8 so I don't know what's the problem.
it has no problem compiling the document, but when I checked around it does this only for one lyx document I have, and there's nothing different in that document than others

Well, it is not an error but a warning than you can deactivate. I am not sure what  mean "auto-legacy" (no use  of  inputenc?) but my guess  it that is related with the fact that LaTeX switched to utf8 as default in 2018 (but de facto standard much before),  whereas  LyX maintained obstinately the default encoding latin9 even in 2,3.7, so maybe LyX make this test because is expecting inconsistent uses of inputenc because mixing old and new files.
